# Toggle Checkbox and send query in background to update database

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

As soon as someone toggles a checkbox. I want a the value sent to a php page for it to update it in my database.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="tg-optionbox">
    <span>Promotional Video</span>
    <span class="tg-iosstylcheckbox">
     <input type="checkbox" id="video" name="video" value="video">
     <label for="video"></label>
      <div id="echo2"></div>
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "get/update-feature.php",
          data: {
              value: $('input:checkbox:checker').val()
          },
          success: function(data) {
              $('#echo2').html(data); 
          }
      });
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
    <?
$sent_value = $_POST['value'];

if(isset($sent_value)){
        //update database
        echo "updated";
}else{
        //update database
}

        ?>
```

Currently, my jquery doesn't work. How I need it:

- They click the orange checkbox toggle
- Jquery recognises this and sends the checkbox value to my php page
- my php page gets the value and puts it in the database

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Any errors?  Does your AJAX request happen?

Comment: On the php page, if it has sent a value, it will echo 'updated' into the div. But it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help you.

> HTML: Not Changed

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="tg-optionbox">
    <span>Promotional Video</span>
    <span class="tg-iosstylcheckbox">
     <input type="checkbox" id="video" name="video" value="video">
     <label for="video"></label>
      <div id="echo2"></div>
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

> JavaScript: Changed

Replaced: `value: $('input:checkbox:checker').val()` by: `value: $(this).prop("checked") ? 1 : 0`

You have to send the value of the clicked checkbox. So you must use `$(this)`.

To get the value of the `checkbox` use `.prop("checked")`. If the returned value is `true`, then it is checked. If it is `false`, then it is not checked.

So if the checkbox is checked, 1 is sent. If not, 0 is sent

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "get/update-feature.php",
          data: {
              value: $(this).prop("checked") ? 1 : 0
          },
          success: function(data) {
              $('#echo2').html(data);
          }
      });
  });
});
```

> PHP: Changed

If the value is equal to 1 or value equal to 0

```
<?php
$sent_value = $_POST['value'];

if(isset($sent_value)){
    if ($sent_value == 1) {
        echo "Checked" ;
    }
    else {
        echo "Un Checked" ;
    }
}
else{
    echo "Error" ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of echo use "return true" if success else false in php code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#video").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "get/update-feature.php",
          data: {
              value: $('input[type=checkbox]').val()
          },
          success: function(data) {
              $('#result').html(data); 
          }
      });
  });
});



<div class="form-group">
  <div class="tg-optionbox">
    <span>Promotional Video</span>
    <span class="tg-iosstylcheckbox">
     <input type="checkbox" id="video" name="video" value="video">
     <label for="video"></label>
      <div id="echo2"><p id="result"></p></div>
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

The error is in `$('input:checkbox:checker').val()` so the value is not sent to php file and the `success` method expects a return value in php. We need to use "return" instead of "echo"

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why

Comment: error is in $('input:checkbox:checker').val() so the value is not sent to php file and success function expects return value in php we need to use "return"  not "echo".

Answer (score 0):

Use [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler :

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    var name = $(this).val();
    var check = $(this).attr('checked');
    //Your Ajax code
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to have worked, is there any way of troubleshooting what part isn't working